# Check the expiry date of a Certificate in UNIX

Tags: unix, certificate

I want to check the expiry date of some certificates.

I used

```
keytool -list -v certicate_name

keytool -list -v spid_1234.pem
```

But it is not giving me the expiry date of the required certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use openssl:

```
openssl x509 -in cert.pem -inform PEM -noout -enddate
```

`cert.pem` should be PEM encoded. If you have DER encoded certificate (just binary data, no base64) then you can switch to `-inform DER`.

More information can be found [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html).